# In Deep Learning, how much does randomness help generalization?

Tags: conv-neural-network, backpropagation, randomness

Let's assume at the beginning the NN is initialized with random weights, then the Backpropagation "shapes" the weights but the signal is strongest close to the final layer (where it gets computed) and the more the depth the more the signal gets attenuated (Vanishing Gradient) or distorted (Exploding Gradient), so the the Initial Layers should be fitted less optimally than the Final ones.

This should make the initial layers be more affected by Random Initial Conditions than the Final ones

Does it mean this random initialization actually helps the CNN to generalize or on the contrary does it mean the Initial Layers are trained sub-optimally hence there is space for improvement for example with different signal propagation mechanisms ?

Answer (score 1):

Most recent architectures incorporate skip-connections which heavily alleviates (if not completely solves) the vanishing and exploding gradients problem. Actually, the paper [The Shattered Gradients Problem: If resnets are the answer, then what is the question?](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.08591) by (Balduzzi et al., 2017) claims that the problem is not vanishing/exploding gradients but rather *shattered* gradients.

The purpose of random initialization is *symmetry breaking*, not generalization. I wouldn't consider it a regularization method because it doesn't really restrict the effective hypothesis space like weight-penalty and early-stopping does. Unless your initialization strategy is designed to keep the weights within a small region of parameter-space during optimization -- but then the generalization ability would be due to the valid range of initial values, not the fact that randomness is used.

With proper technique (skip-connections + batch-norm + good init), I don't think the initial layers would be trained substantially worse than deeper layers. You are correct that without these, the early layers would not be trained well, which is [unsupervised layer-wise pretraining](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/3048-greedy-layer-wise-training-of-deep-networks.pdf) was used early on for training deep networks.

Comment: I think that's how stopped training works... because you start with weights initialised around zero, stopped training works...